# Exception: Access to the path is denied while renaming file in c#?

Tags: c#

I am using File.Move operation to rename the file, I am picking the file from same folder and after renaming dropping into the same folder. It is working fine for sometimes but sometime it will throw an above mentioned exception. Why it is behaving like this?

Note: I configured this .exe application in Task Scheduler, it will run every 5 min.

Please see Sample Code below:

```
private static void LocalZipFileRename()
    {
        try
        {

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FTPZipSource);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
                logger.Info("Renaming Local Zip filename" + filename);
                if(!filename.Contains("StringValue_"))
                {
                    File.Move(FTPZipSource + filename, FTPZipSource + "StringValue_" + filename);
                    logger.Info("Renaming Local Zip filename, Completed" + filename);
                }

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Exception at LocalZipFileRename" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you give us a short example code?

Comment: Can you show us some code? "I am picking the file from same folder and after renaming dropping into the same folder", which sounds like you are doing two operations, but the `File.Move()` does both of those things in one operation. Using [google](http://www.google.com) it appears you can have the problem if a program is locking the file. You might be inadvertently locking the file with some previous operations that were not `Close()`ed, for example.

Comment: "Runs every 5 minutes". I assume some program is creating the zip files continuously, if that program doesn't release the file handle to the zip it created then you will get the exception you see. Or if the FTP program (assumption here from the `FTPZipSource`) doesn't release the file handle, or takes some time to release it, then you will see the same exception. You might be trying to rename a zip file that the program is *still in the process of zipping*, or that the FTP program *is still in the process of transferring*. Lots of assumptions here due to the limited information given.